# Highcharts padding for range selector when displaying last label on y axis?

Tags: highcharts

When I display the last label of a yaxis, the spacing of the range selector gets crowded.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/georgeludwig/FttkQ/7/

You can see how the "75" and "30" are kind of jammed in there.

Is there any way to get more space around the range selector? i've been messing around with various padding values, and nothing works.

code:

```
<code>
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            alignTicks: false
        },

        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time Published',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite: true,

            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                showLastLabel: true,
                title: {
                    text: '% Audience Coverage',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },

            }],

        series: [{

            yAxis: 0,
            type: "scatter",
            data:[ [1142294400000,2],
                   [1183334400000,5],
                   [1199232000000,18],
                   [1230768000000,9],
                   [1262304000000,4],
                   [1294012800000,20],
                   [1325548800000,1],
                   [1357084800000,6] ]

        }, {

            yAxis: 1,
            type: "areaspline",
            data:[ [1142294400000,9],
                   [1183334400000,10],
                   [1199232000000,15],
                   [1230768000000,25],
                   [1262304000000,35],
                   [1294012800000,46],
                   [1325548800000,47],
                   [1357084800000,68] ]

        }]
    });
});
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxPadding (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) with setting tickInterval (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)

http://jsfiddle.net/FttkQ/9/

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            showLastLabel: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Time Published',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            opposite: true,
            tickInterval:10,
            maxPadding:1

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            showLastLabel: false,
            maxPadding:0.2,
            tickInterval:25,
            title: {
                text: '% Audience Coverage',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },

        }],
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, however what you've presented is kind of a hack. It's the equivalent of having one more tick interval, and not displaying the last tick interval. At the top of the graph, I want to see the max value, in this case, 75, rather than seeing 75 and the space of an extra tick interval above it.

Answer (score 0):

@ Sebastian Bochan, Cant we use rangeSelector? why does this rangeSelector wont work for zoom button?

rangeSelector: {
            inputPosition: {
                y: 5
            }
        }

Comment: I introduced you one of solutions.

Comment: rangeSelector only work on highstock, it does not work with highcharts

Comment: Because navigator / rangeSelector is available only in highstock.